# stop scroll when you click on body or move your finger on the phone

Tags: javascript, jquery, scrolltop

I have several scrolling options on my website after clicking the button:

```
 $(".button").click(function () {
      $('html,body').animate({
         scrollTop: $("div").offset().top
      });
  });
```

How can I stop scrolling if the user clicks anywhere with the mouse or clicks a finger on the phone's screen to stop it?

Comment: this link might help you `tutorialrepublic.com/jquery-tutorial/jquery-stop-animations.php`

Comment: See https://api.jquery.com/stop/